# Column space of an $m \times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I met a problem like this:

> Suppose the column space of an $m\times n$ matrix is all of $\mathbb R^3$.
>
> What can you say about $\mathit m$?
>
> What can you say about $\mathit n$?
>
> What can you say about the rank?

From $\mathbf C(A)$ = $\mathbb R^3$, I know that $\mathit m$ = 3 and the column rank = 3. Then what about $\mathit n$? The answer shows $\mathit n\geqslant$3, which I didn't follow. Why should $\mathit n$ has to be more than or equal to 3?

Comment: To those downvoting and voting to close, they have _clearly_ shown individual work here; this is an almost solved exercise, and they are simply stuck on the final part. That's a lot more context than many other posts on this site. What do you find wrong with it?

Comment: @MorganRodgers It's a first time poster. There are a couple of formatting and formulation issues, which can be worked out, but content-wise, this is miles above most homework questions we get. Also, answers (including brief answers) should **not** be in comments. The comment box _itself_ says so. So I have no idea why you would think that that's where my answer belongs.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Your votes are yours to give. Not arguing there, and I'm not telling you you _should_ revoke it. I am not even claiming you are a downvoter. But your reasons make no sense to me. And if these are the reasons of the down and close voters, then I personally think they are not being helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column space has three dimensions, then you need at least three columns to make that happen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I realized I made a mistake here. It is told that () = ℝ^3, that means you have to get 3 independent columns which indicates that there has to be at least 3 columns in the matrix. As for m-the number of rows in this matrix, I get the answer from the definition of vector space, for ℝ3 means 3 real number components in the column which we can see as a vector.

Comment: But I am not sure it is correct or not.I am still confused about the space that span by matrix here. In this case, the answer is m=3, which I think is restricted by the definition of vector space. But if we see this matrix in row space way, then the 3 rows may lie in the same line or something. If we have a forth row which happens to be a linear combination of the first three rows, the hypothesis of ‘the column space of an ×n matrix is all of ℝ3’ will stand still?

Comment: @bulala We are specifically asked about the _column space_ of the matrix, so looking at the row vectors won't really get us anywhere. Yes, since each column has to be elements of the column space, and the column space has to be $\Bbb R^3$, we must have three rows. And since the column space is three-dimensional, the rank (column rank or row rank, they are the same) must also be $3$. And I guess the a different way to phrase what I said in my answer is that the rank cannot be higher than the number of columns, so we need at least three columns.

Comment: get it. thanks so much.